# insertafter data stuck in the cell above it

Tags: php, html, jquery, insertafter

I am having an issue where my .`insertafter` data is showing up stuck inside one cell of its parent data despite the fact it is its own row with its own div. (Please see the picture below)

[image: picture of the layout]

The AJAX code that is grabbing the data for the `insertafter` is as follows:

```
function options(id){           
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',       url: my_ajax.ajax_url,      
        data: {             action: 'options_function',
        cid : id
        },      
success: function (data) {
var $newElement=jQuery("<div>",
{id:'ideal_option',html:data}
)
$newElement.insertAfter(jQuery('[data-id="' + id + '"]').closest('tr'))
```

Here is the PHP and HTML for the table itself.

```
echo "<table id ='ideal_option' >"; 
        echo '<tr style="display:inline-table; width:100%">';
        echo '<th>' . "Table". '</th>', '<th>' . "Size". '</th>', '<th>' . "Name". '</th>', '<th>' . "Party". '</th>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '<tr>';
foreach($check_availability as $available){ 
    $tbl_id=$available->id;
    $foh_nmbr=$available->FOH_Number;
    $tbl_type=$available->Type;
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $foh_nmbr . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $tbl_type . '</td>';
    echo("<td><select>");
foreach($Staff_On_Duty as $person){         
    echo("<option value = $sf_name_option&nbsp;$sl_name_option");
    if (($sf_name_option == $sf_name) && ($sl_name_option == $sl_name)) echo (" selected"); 
    echo(">$sf_name_option&nbsp;$sl_name_option</option>"); 
}
echo("</select></td>");
    
    echo '<td>' . "<button id='party' class='button' onclick='party($tbl_id, $cid)'><i class='icon fas fa-globe'></i></button>" . '</td>'; 
echo '</tr>';}
echo '</table>';
```

I have tried adding styles to the table such as width:100% and display (literally tried them all) but nothing takes this whole table out of the cell above it.

**EDIT 1**
using the suggestion of

jQuery('[data-id="' + id + '"]').closest('tr').find('td:last').append($newElement)
It places the appended data next to instead of under. I have tried all display types on the tbody but none place the data under the row.
[image]

**EDIT 2**
when using this code, the result is

```
var $newTR = jQuery("<tr>")
var $newTD = jQuery("<td>",{id:'ideal_option',html:data, colspan:4}) // I assume 4 columns
$newTR.append($newTD)

// Then here, .insertAfter() is the right method
$newTR.insertAfter(jQuery('[data-id="' + id + '"]'))
```

[image]

**Edit 3**
the code:

```
var $newElement=jQuery("<tr>",
{id:'ideal_option',html:data}
)
$newElement.insertAfter(jQuery('[data-id="' + id + '"]').closest('tr'))
```

provides:
[image]

Comment: In the AJAX code you provide is that `<dvi>` typo actually in your code or just transposed here?

Comment: transposition typo. fixed

Comment: Hi @Kris where exactly you need to show your datas ?

Comment: hi, I need it to show up under the initial row instead of to the side

Comment: you need to put new `tr` inside td ?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery [.insertAfter()](https://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) is inserting an element after the target provided as argument.

So here, `$newElement.insertAfter(jQuery('[data-id="' + id + '"]').closest('tr'))`, is inserting a `<dvi>` element after the closing tag of the closest `tr` element.

Even if you fix the `dvi` obvious typo...

You would be inserting a `<div>` element inside a `<table>` and therefore is invalid HTML.

I guess you should look for the [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) method instead...

That would be something like this, to append a `div` to the last `td` of a `tr`:

```
jQuery('[data-id="' + id + '"]').closest('tr').find('td:last').append($newElement)
```

---

**EDIT** base on comment below.

> This works-ish. It is placing the new div(yes typo) next to instead of under the row.

If you want to have an additional row under, Then create a `td` inside a `tr`!

Try this:

```
var $newTR = jQuery("<tr>")
var $newTD = jQuery("<td>",{id:'ideal_option',html:data, colspan:4}) // I assume 4 columns
$newTR.append($newTD)

// Then here, .insertAfter() is the right method
$newTR.insertAfter(jQuery('[data-id="' + id + '"]'))
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This works-ish. It is placing the new div(yes typo) next to instead of under the row. I tried all display types and none place it under.  I was placing the display types on the tbody id=list-table

Comment: Much appreciated.  Not sure it is as intended however. I added an edit #2. I also added a #3 that I tried that is closest but still not quite there.